# Filling forms on different websites using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm a beginner to Python and trying to start my very first project, which revolves around creating a program to automatically fill in pre-defined values in forms on various websites.

Currently, I'm struggling to find a way to identify web elements using the text shown on the website. For example, website A's email field shows "Email:" while another website might show "Fill in your email". In such cases, finding the element using ID or name would not be possible (unless I write a different set of code for each website) as they vary from website to website.

So, my question is, is it possible to write a code where it will scan all the fields -> check the text -> then fill in the values based on the texts that are associated with each field?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you know the markup of the page, and you can write code to parse this page. In this case you should use xpath, lxml, beautiful soup, selenium etc. You can look at many manuals on google or youtube, just type "python scraping"
But if you want to write a program able to understand random page on a random site and understand what it should do, it is very difficult, it's a complex task with using machine learning. I guess this task is completely not for beginners.